# Switch between Invoice And Orders MVC

Tags: design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have an MVC view where a show Orders data with some filters.

Id like know if I can reuse the same ViewModel - Controller - class using two radio button to switch from orders and invoices.

Following MVC pattern is that a good practice ?

Or i have to rewrite another ViewModel-Controller-View for the invoces ?

Comment: i think you can do this, by taking two POCO classes one for Orders and Other for Invoices..And Bind the data according to your choice

Comment: what is POCO ? You mean i can use same code and place two radio button ?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5d065a/poco-classes-in-entity-framework/

Comment: yes, you can place two radio buttons and on selection of these, you can add your code. and bind data accordingly.